# C# - Post XML to ASP.net Web Service Error - LoadRequest Failure - Error parsing request: Failure -

Tags: asp.net

I am getting a weired error when submitting  XML data to a webapi. Here is the input xml , code and response. I am using a simple C# console program using VS 2017. The xml works OK in postman. But issue for C# console program.

To reproduce the error :

step1) Save the input xml eg : c:\work\r1.xml
step2) create c# console program and paste the below code.
ste3)  Get the error "LoadRequest Failure - Error parsing request: Failure - Response Group Code Required"

a) input xml :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
    <tem:SoapRequest>           
        <tem:request>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:ClientNumber>12345666</tem:ClientNumber>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:BusinessUnit>bizUnit-blah blah</tem:BusinessUnit>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:ValidationKey>13123131313-E452-487F-BFF2-0EFA2EFB86CB</tem:ValidationKey>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:DataYear>2017</tem:DataYear>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:DataMonth>11</tem:DataMonth>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:CmplDataYear>2017</tem:CmplDataYear>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:CmplDataMonth>11</tem:CmplDataMonth>
            <tem:TotalRevenue>100.00</tem:TotalRevenue>
            <!--totalrevneue: For Negative charges, the first position should have a minus ‘-‘indicator.:-->
            <tem:ClientTracking>VG-01-25-2017 blah</tem:ClientTracking>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:ResponseType>D2</tem:ResponseType>
            <!--respond type D for detailed, 2 for two decimal:-->
            <tem:ReturnFileCode>T</tem:ReturnFileCode>
            <!--returnfilecode. 0 live calc, Q quote, T in progress:-->
            <tem:STAN/>
            <tem:MasterTransId>0</tem:MasterTransId>
            <!--mastertransid. T for to update in progresss transaction by using the master suretax transid. if not use, value of 0 should be provided.-->
            <tem:BillingAddress>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:PrimaryAddressLine>1234 abc line</tem:PrimaryAddressLine>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:SecondaryAddressLine>header</tem:SecondaryAddressLine>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:County/>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:City>wichita</tem:City>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:State>ks</tem:State>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:PostalCode>67207</tem:PostalCode>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:Plus4/>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:Country/>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:Geocode/>
                <tem:VerifyAddress>true</tem:VerifyAddress>
            </tem:BillingAddress>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:ShipToAddress>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:PrimaryAddressLine>1234 abc line</tem:PrimaryAddressLine>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:SecondaryAddressLine>header</tem:SecondaryAddressLine>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:County/>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:City>wichita</tem:City>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:State>ks</tem:State>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:PostalCode>67207</tem:PostalCode>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:Plus4/>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:Country/>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:Geocode/>
                <tem:VerifyAddress>true</tem:VerifyAddress>
            </tem:ShipToAddress>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:ShipFromAddress>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:PrimaryAddressLine>1234 abc line</tem:PrimaryAddressLine>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:SecondaryAddressLine>header</tem:SecondaryAddressLine>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:County/>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:City>wichita</tem:City>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:State>ks</tem:State>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:PostalCode>67207</tem:PostalCode>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:Plus4/>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:Country/>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:Geocode/>
                <tem:VerifyAddress>true</tem:VerifyAddress>
            </tem:ShipFromAddress>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:OrderPlacementAddress>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:PrimaryAddressLine>1234 abc line</tem:PrimaryAddressLine>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:SecondaryAddressLine>header</tem:SecondaryAddressLine>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:County/>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:City>wichita</tem:City>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:State>ks</tem:State>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:PostalCode>67207</tem:PostalCode>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:Plus4/>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:Country/>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:Geocode/>
                <tem:VerifyAddress>true</tem:VerifyAddress>
            </tem:OrderPlacementAddress>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:OrderApprovalAddress>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:PrimaryAddressLine>1234 abc line</tem:PrimaryAddressLine>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:SecondaryAddressLine>header</tem:SecondaryAddressLine>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:County/>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:City>wichita</tem:City>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:State>ks</tem:State>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:PostalCode>67207</tem:PostalCode>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:Plus4/>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:Country/>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <tem:Geocode/>
                <tem:VerifyAddress>true</tem:VerifyAddress>
            </tem:OrderApprovalAddress>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:ItemList>
                <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                <tem:Item>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:LineNumber>1</tem:LineNumber>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:InvoiceNumber>1blah</tem:InvoiceNumber>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:CustomerNumber>123blah</tem:CustomerNumber>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:LocationCode/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:TransDate>2017-11-01</tem:TransDate>
                    <!--transdate mm-dd-yyyy. the right one yyyy-mm-dd-->
                    <tem:Revenue>100.00</tem:Revenue>
                    <!--revenue For Negative charges, the first position should have a minus ‘-‘indicator.:-->
                    <tem:TaxIncludedCode>0</tem:TaxIncludedCode>
                    <!--taxincluded 0 – Default (No Tax Included) 1 – Tax Included in Revenue :-->
                    <tem:Units>10</tem:Units>
                    <!--units =quantity:-->
                    <tem:TaxSitusRule>22</tem:TaxSitusRule>

                    <tem:TransTypeCode>990101</tem:TransTypeCode>
                    <!--transtypecode. 990101 = GM 0000-000:-->
                    <tem:SalesTypeCode>D</tem:SalesTypeCode>

                    <tem:RegulatoryCode>01</tem:RegulatoryCode>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:TaxExemptionCodeList>
                        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                        <tem:string/>
                    </tem:TaxExemptionCodeList>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:UDF/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:UDF2/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:FreightOnBoard/>
                    <tem:ShipFromPOB>false</tem:ShipFromPOB>
                    <tem:MailOrder>false</tem:MailOrder>
                    <tem:CommonCarrier>false</tem:CommonCarrier>
                    <tem:AuxRevenue>0</tem:AuxRevenue>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:AuxRevenueType/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:CostCenter/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:GLAccount/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:MaterialGroup/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:Parameter1/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:Parameter2/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:Parameter3/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:Parameter4/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:Parameter5/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:Parameter6/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:Parameter7/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:Parameter8/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:Parameter9/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:Parameter10/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:RuleOverride/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:CurrencyCode/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:ExemptReasonCode/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:BillingAddress>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:PrimaryAddressLine/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SecondaryAddressLine/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:County/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:City/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:State/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:PostalCode/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:Plus4/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:Country/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:Geocode/>
                        <tem:VerifyAddress>true</tem:VerifyAddress>
                    </tem:BillingAddress>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:ShipToAddress>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:PrimaryAddressLine/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SecondaryAddressLine/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:County/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:City/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:State/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:PostalCode>90210</tem:PostalCode>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:Plus4/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:Country/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:Geocode/>
                        <tem:VerifyAddress>true</tem:VerifyAddress>
                    </tem:ShipToAddress>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:ShipFromAddress>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:PrimaryAddressLine/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SecondaryAddressLine/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:County/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:City/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:State/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:PostalCode>67217</tem:PostalCode>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:Plus4/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:Country/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:Geocode/>
                        <tem:VerifyAddress>true</tem:VerifyAddress>
                    </tem:ShipFromAddress>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:OrderPlacementAddress>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:PrimaryAddressLine/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SecondaryAddressLine/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:County/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:City/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:State/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:PostalCode/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:Plus4/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:Country/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:Geocode/>
                        <tem:VerifyAddress>true</tem:VerifyAddress>
                    </tem:OrderPlacementAddress>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <tem:OrderApprovalAddress>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:PrimaryAddressLine/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:SecondaryAddressLine/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:County/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:City/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:State/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:PostalCode/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:Plus4/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:Country/>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:Geocode/>
                        <tem:VerifyAddress>true</tem:VerifyAddress>
                    </tem:OrderApprovalAddress>
                </tem:Item>
            </tem:ItemList>
        </tem:request>
    </tem:SoapRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

b) code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;



namespace ConsoleApp{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            PostXML();

        }

        catch (Exception ex) { Console.Write(ex.Message);                    

        }

        finally
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }



    public static void PostXML()
    {
        WebRequest req = null;
        WebResponse rsp = null;
        try
        {            

string fileName = @"C:\work\r1.xml";
        string uri = "<type endpoint url here>";
        req = WebRequest.Create(uri);               
        req.Method = "POST";       
        req.ContentType = "text/xml";  

        StreamWriter writer = new      StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());                
        writer.WriteLine(GetTextFromXMLFile(fileName));
        writer.Close();                
        rsp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream());
        XmlTextReader  objXMLReader = new XmlTextReader(sr);                
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load(objXMLReader);                
        XmlDocument  XMLResponse = xmldoc;
        XMLResponse.Save(@"c:\work\response.xml");
        Console.WriteLine(xmldoc.InnerXml);
        objXMLReader.Close();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This program is expected to throw 
             WebException on successful run." +
                    "\n\nException Message :" + e.Message);
            if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {

                 Console.WriteLine("Status Code : {0}",                  
                 ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode);

            Console.WriteLine("Status Description : {0}",
        (HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            if (req != null) req.GetRequestStream().Close();
            if (rsp != null) rsp.GetResponseStream().Close();
        }

    }


    private static string GetTextFromXMLFile(string file)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
        string ret = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        return ret;
    }
```

}
}

c) response :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap:Body><SoapRequestResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><SoapRequestResult><ExtensionData/><Successful>N</Successful><ResponseCode>1190</ResponseCode><HeaderMessage>LoadRequest Failure - Error parsing request: Failure - Response Group Code Required</HeaderMessage><ItemMessages/><ClientTracking>VG-01-25-2017 blah</ClientTracking><TransId>576787064</TransId>
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: It looks like the web api doesn't like that your XML doesn't have a ResponseGroupCode node.

Comment: It was my mistake. The endpoint was wrong (at line req = WebRequest.Create(uri);    ) . The code is correct. After correcting the uri value to the correct endpont, all worked OK. Thanks agian.